# Maven project in Eclipse show duplicate sources

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have Maven project  in Eclipse which have java classes inside.

The problem is that I have two folders to view the sources, one is **Java Resources** and the second is **src**.

[image]

Why? and how to get rid of the **src** folder?

Comment: Go to Properties of your project, set your source directory as you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project ->Maven->Update Maven Project.

This should help you recover correct structure.